# Boundedness issue of inverting an infinite Jordan block in $\ell^2(\mathbb Z)$ (shift operator)

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

I find myself confused about the following thought. Consider the right-shift operator $R$ on $\ell^2(\mathbb Z).$ It has spectrum $\{|z| = 1\}.$ Now pick $\lambda>1.$ Then if $y=(R-\lambda)x,$ we have
$$
y_n = x_{n-1} - \lambda x_n, x = (..., x_{-1}, x_0, x_1 , ...)
$$
Then if $x_n$ decays fast as $n\to +\infty,$ in particular $x_n\lambda^n \to 0,$ we have
$$
x_0 = y_1 + \lambda y_2 + \lambda^2 y_3 + ... \space(*)
$$

Now pick a value $y\in \ell^2 (\mathbb Z)$ with strictly positive elements, but decays slowly at a slow rate, say $y_n = 1/|n|.$ Let $y^{(n)}$ be the finite truncation of $y,$ making all elements except for the $(-n)$-th all the way to the $n$-th zero. Then $y^{(n)} \to y$ strongly on $\ell^2(\mathbb Z).$

The inverse $(R-\lambda)^{-1}$ exists and is bounded, since $\lambda$ is not in the spectrum. Let $\xi_0$ be the map $\ell^2(\mathbb Z) \to \mathbb C : x\mapsto x_0.$ Then $T = \xi_0 \circ (R-\lambda)^{-1}$ is a bounded linear functional. Note that whenever $y$ has only finitely many nonzero elements, then there exists $N$ such that $x_n = 0$ for $n>N.$ (Otherwise, $x$ grows exponentially in one direction, and cannot be in $\ell^2(\mathbb Z).$) Therefore, the value $Ty$ is given by $(*)$ above. Thus,
$$
Ty^{(n)} \to \infty \text{ as }n \to \infty
$$
since the series $(*)$ diverges for such a slowly decaying sequence $y.$ However, $T$ is bounded, and $Ty_n \to Ty,$ contradiction.

**So, what is wrong here?**

Answer (score 1):

$$
\begin{split}
(R-\lambda I)=-\lambda(I-\frac{1}{\lambda}R)\\
(R-\lambda I)^{-1}=-\frac{1}{\lambda}\sum_{k=0}^\infty \lambda^{-k}R^k
\end{split}
$$
with the latter series justified since $\|\frac{1}{\lambda}R\|<1$.  From this
$$
x_n=-\sum_{k=0}^\infty\lambda^{-k-1}y_{n-k}=-\frac{1}{\lambda}y_n-\frac{1}{\lambda^2}y_{n-1}-\frac{1}{\lambda^3}y_{n-2}-\frac{1}{\lambda^4}y_{n-3}-\ldots
$$
which is entirely the other direction from $(*)$ in the original post.  It is also straightforward to verify that this is consistent with $x_n-\lambda x_{n+1}=y_{n+1}$.

Comment: So do you spot where the issue is?

Comment: @MaJoad:  How can your formula $(*)$ be correct?  The value of $x_n$ depends on past values of $y$, not future values.  The future and past values are independent.

Comment: I think (*) is correct - it is almost symmetric - I can express $x_n$ both in terms of past values AND/OR future values. Your formula is also correct, and will lead to the same contradiction for $0<\lambda < 1.$

Comment: @MaJoad: My formula does not hold for $\lambda<1$ because the power series does not converge.  The proof is based on the Taylor series for $\frac{1}{1-z}$ which converges for $|z|<1$.  You gave no proof of $(*)$, just asserted it.  It looks like some reverse induction from $\infty$ to $0$ where you assume the result at $\infty$, and show that if it holds for $n+1$ it holds for $n$.  My formula is not based on induction, but on Taylor series.

Comment: What you say is true for the series of $R$. What I am asking is different. If we forget about $R,$ and write the series in the form $(*)$, then we notice that although it diverges for some $y$, it also works correctly for some $y.$ I am concerned with the particular small subset where it works correctly. I am NOT saying $(*)$ is true for every $y$ or $x$

Comment: @MaJoad: You did not prove $(*)$ for any $y$.

Comment: I haven't written a proof in detail, but I have clearly stated that $(*)$ is true when $x_n$ decays sufficiently fast as $n$ increases, which is obviously true.

Comment: @MaJoad:  Just because the right-hand side of $(*)$ converges for some $y$ does not mean it's equal to $(R-\lambda I)^{-1}y$.  You didn't prove that.  The formula in $(*)$ is not compatible with the one I gave.  Fix $y$.  Fix some $n_0$.  Change some values of $y$ starting at $n_0+1$ forward.  The formula $(*)$ will give a different result for $x_{n_0}$ than my formula.  Because my formula only depends on the values of $y$ at $n_0$ downward - so the result for $x_{n_0}$ doesn't change.  Both formulas cannot be right.  I proved mine with Taylor series.

Comment: "Just because the right-hand side of (∗) converges for some  does not mean"

I do not mean that. The difference between $x_0$ and my partial sum in $(*)$ is $\lambda^n x_n,$ which I assume to converge to 0. Hence we get the convergence. I know your concern, and that's exactly where I am confused.

Comment: @MaJoad:  Just because the difference is $\lambda^n x_n$ which converges to zero doesn't mean this is the same as the value of $(R-\lambda I)^{-1}y$ at coordinate $0$.  You're doing reverse induction where you assume something is true for $n+1$, prove it for $n$.  There is no base case.  This isn't a valid proof.